# Creating a function with Execute immediate PL/SQL oracle but not getting the output

Tags: database, oracle, function, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CDE_REC IS TABLE OF CDE_REC_TYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CDE_REC_TYPE AS OBJECT ( EmpId VARCHAR2(8), counter VARCHAR2(5), dayJ VARCHAR2(8),typeD NUMBER, unitD VARCHAR2(5));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATA(EmpID VARCHAR2, DateFilter VARCHAR2)
 RETURN CDE_REC IS
    TMP_CDE_TBL CDE_REC := CDE_REC();
    v_sql VARCHAR(10000);
  BEGIN 
   v_sql := 'with table1 as (  
   select  id, counter,  dayJ, type,  
      decode( counter,  ''XY'', ''7'',''AB'', ''7'', ''BC'', ''7'', ''CD'', ''7'', ''EF'', ''7'', ''GH'', ''7'', ''IJ'', ''7'', ''KL'', ''7'',  ''MN'', ''7H'', ''OP'', ''7H'',  
      ''QR'', ''8'', ''FF'', ''8'',  ''ST'', ''9'', ''UV'', ''9'', ''XY'', ''9'', ''YZ'', ''9'', ''AA'', ''9'', ''BB'', ''9'', ''CC'', ''9'', ''DD'', ''9'', ''EE'', ''9''  ) as Lot_Don,  
      lag (dayJ, 1) over (partition by id, counter order by dayJ asc, type asc) as dayJ_ER,  
      lag (type, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ asc, type asc) as E_PREC,  
      nvl(VALJ,0) as valj_7,  
      nvl( lag (VALJ, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ, type asc), 0) as EARValJ,  
      nvl(LOT7,0) as valh_7,  
      nvl( lag (LOT7, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ, type asc), 0) as Data7_Ear,  
      nvl(LOT8,0) as valj_8,  
      nvl( lag (LOT8, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ, type asc), 0) as LOT8_E,  
      nvl(LOT8_RH,0) as valh_8,  
      nvl( lag (LOT8_RH, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ, type asc), 0) as LOT8_RH_E,  
      nvl(LOT9,0) as valj_9,  
      nvl( lag (LOT9, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ, type asc), 0) as LOT9_EH,  
      nvl(LOT9_H,0) as valh_9,  nvl( lag (LOT9_H, 1) over(partition by id, counter order by dayJ, type asc), 0) as LOT9_E  
   from  tableUsed1  
   where  counter in (''XY'', ''AB'', ''BC'', ''CD'', ''EF'', ''GH'', ''IJ'', ''KL'', ''MN'', ''OP'', ''QR'', ''FF'', ''ST'', ''UV'', ''XY'', ''YZ'', ''AA'', ''BB'', ''CC'', ''DD'', ''EE'')  
      AND id IN ('|| EmpID || ') 
      and dayJ = to_char(to_date(' || DateFilter || ', ''dd.mm.yyyy''), ''yyyymmdd'') )  , 
table2 as (  
   select  id, counter, dayJ, Lot_Don,  
      case  when exists (
      select 1 from tableC  
      where eID = id  
         and to_date(dayJ,''YYYYMMDD'') between St_Date_Val and nvl(End_Date_V, to_date(''20991231'', ''YYYYMMDD''))  
         and DATATAB is not null 
         and DATATAB in (''151'',''152'',''420'')
      )  then  
      case  when Lot_Don = ''7H'' then round(valh_7 / 3600 / 6.84, 2)  
         when Lot_Don = ''8'' then round(valh_8 / 3600 / 6.84, 2)  
         when Lot_Don = ''9H'' then round(valh_9 / 3600 / 6.84, 2)  
         when Lot_Don = ''7'' then valj_7  
         when Lot_Don = ''8J'' then valj_8  
         when Lot_Don = ''9'' then valj_9  
      end  
      when exists (
         select 1 
         from tableC  
         where eID = id  
            and to_date(dayJ,''YYYYMMDD'') between St_Date_Val and nvl(End_Date_V, to_date(''20991231'', ''YYYYMMDD''))  
            and DATATAB is not null 
            and DATATAB in (''704''))  
       then  
          case  when Lot_Don = ''7H'' then round(valh_7 / 3600 / 6.72, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''8'' then round(valh_8 / 3600 / 6.72, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''9H'' then round(valh_9 / 3600 / 6.72, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''7'' then valj_7 
          when Lot_Don = ''8J'' then valj_8  
          when Lot_Don = ''9'' then valj_9  
       end  
       else  
          case  when Lot_Don = ''7H'' then round(valh_7 / 3600 / 7, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''8'' then round(valh_8 / 3600 / 7, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''9H'' then round(valh_9 / 3600 / 7, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''7'' then valj_7  
          when Lot_Don = ''8J'' then valj_8  
          when Lot_Don = ''9'' then valj_9  
       end  
       end  as VALP,  
       case  when exists (
       select 1 
       from tableC  
       where eID = id  
          and to_date(dayJ,''YYYYMMDD'') between St_Date_Val and nvl(End_Date_V, to_date(''20991231'', ''YYYYMMDD''))  
          and DATATAB is not null 
          and DATATAB in (''151'',''152'',''420''))  
       then  case  when Lot_Don = ''7H'' then round(Data7_Ear / 3600 / 6.84, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''8'' then round(LOT8_RH_E / 3600 / 6.84, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''9H'' then round(LOT9_E / 3600 / 6.84, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''7'' then EARValJ  
          when Lot_Don = ''8J'' then LOT8_E  
          when Lot_Don = ''9'' then LOT9_EH  
       end  when exists (
       select 1 
       from tableC  
       where eID = id  
          and to_date(dayJ,''YYYYMMDD'') between St_Date_Val and nvl(End_Date_V, to_date(''20991231'', ''YYYYMMDD''))  
          and DATATAB is not null 
          and DATATAB in (''704''))  then  
       case  when Lot_Don = ''7H'' then round(Data7_Ear / 3600 / 6.72, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''8'' then round(LOT8_RH_E / 3600 / 6.72, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''9H'' then round(LOT9_E / 3600 / 6.72, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''7'' then EARValJ  
          when Lot_Don = ''8J'' then LOT8_E  
          when Lot_Don = ''9'' then LOT9_EH  
          end  
       else  
          case when Lot_Don = ''7H'' then round(Data7_Ear / 3600 / 7, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''8'' then round(LOT8_RH_E / 3600 / 7, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''9H'' then round(LOT9_E / 3600 / 7, 2)  
          when Lot_Don = ''7'' then EARValJ  when Lot_Don = ''8J'' then LOT8_E  
          when Lot_Don = ''9'' then LOT9_EH  
          end  
       end  as DatP_Ear, 
       ''Days'' as unitD  
    from  table1  
    where  ((dayJ >= ''20151101''and dayJ like ''%1101'') or (dayJ >= ''20211102''and dayJ like ''%1102''))  
       and type = ''M''  and ( 
           ( counter in (''XY'', ''AB'', ''BC'', ''CD'', ''EF'', ''GH'', ''IJ'', ''KL'') and valj_7 > 0 )  
          or  ( counter in (''MN'', ''OP'') and valh_7 > 0 )  or  ( counter in (''QR'', ''FF'') and valh_8 > 0 )  
          or  ( counter in (''ST'', ''UV'', ''XY'', ''YZ'', ''AA'', ''BB'', ''CC'', ''DD'', ''EE'') and valj_9 > 0 )  
       )  
       AND id IN (' || EmpID || ') 
       and dayJ = to_char(to_date(' || DateFilter || ', ''dd.mm.yyyy''), ''yyyymmdd'') )  
    select id, counter, dayJ, (sum(VALP) - sum(DatP_Ear)), unitD 
    from table2 
    group by  id, counter, dayJ, Lot_Don, unitD  order by  id, dayJ';


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL BULK COLLECT INTO TMP_CDE_TBL;
    --Initialise la collection
    
    RETURN TMP_CDE_TBL;
  END GET_DATA;
```

I am trying to create a function with two parameters one is an sql query and the other on is the date on which the query needs to filtre down the result. The result is a table which i am trying to pick up in a type object. I have put up this query with execute immediate but unfortunately its not working and i am unable to find the reason why. Any insight on this would be really helpful. Its showing Invalid operation error.

To run this function i am using two type of queries

```
select * from table(GET_DATA('SELECT EmpID FROM CLIENT','02.12.2022'))
select * from table(GET_DATA('SELECT EmpID FROM CLIENT','\'02.12.2022\''))
select GET_DATA('SELECT EmpID FROM CLIENT','02.12.2022') from dual 
select GET_DATA('SELECT EmpID FROM CLIENT','\'02.12.2022\'') from dual
```

Comment: You might need to use BULK COLLECT INTO instead of simply using INTO.

Comment: Saying that something is "not working" doesn't give us a lot of information.  Presumably, you're getting an error.  Post the error.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL? And if you call your function from an anonymous PL/SQL block, assigning the result to a variable, then you'll see any errors it throws properly - calling as you are can hide them. (And `set serveroutput on` or the equivalent for your client to see the `dbms_output` values.) You need `bulk collect` for a start; but what you've posted [won't even compile](https://dbfiddle.uk/fzGB6sAO).

Comment: Just a note that string concatenation as you are using in your dynamic SQL statement is an open door for SQL injection: very insecure. In fact, by inserting a full subquery, you are literally performing SQL injection yourself.

Comment: @AlexPoole=> That's the error i am getting although the function has compiled successfully and in a valid state 

[1] Invalid operation
Message: [1] Invalid operation

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL? In your query it is not needed at all. And why do you store `DATE` values as string? You should **never** do that, it's a design flaw.

Comment: It is a very old progiciel we are using and i know its not a best practise to use dynamic SQL. But the problem is we have a view with this SQL statement without any date and empID filter and it takes more than 10 mins to run but its too much. Hence we want to create a function where in we can pass the empId and the date so that we dont have to go via the view and can cut down the time of the query.

Comment: That doesn't really explain why you're using dynamic SQL. If you want to be able to pass one or many IDs then you can make the first argument a collection, and then the caller can pass or construct a collection (which could be done with the query you're using in your current call). And the second argument could be an actual date instead of a string too. (Even if you are storing dates as string, which is a bad idea; you might just be doing unnecessary conversions on that though.)

Comment: If your view has the same query and projects the same columns, why can't you add the ID and date filters when you query the view? I don't think your manipulations would prevent the optimiser taking that into account. Or have you tried that and it didn't help?

Comment: Using dynamic SQL because for each user the date and the list of EmpIds which he can see will be different based on his securoty clearances

Comment: If you checked the above query it has two with as clauses with two different tables in it without any filter. I want to add the filters on these "with as" queries as well which reduces the sql query time. 
the time of execution of the view while showing  50 Rows 
 Statement 1 executed in 35 Seconds 433 Milliseconds (Max 50 rows)
while if i add the filter in both the tables the result is 
 Statement 1 executed in 1 Seconds 532 Milliseconds (Max 50 rows)

Comment: What happens if you apply the filter to a query against the view? And what happens if you run the final dynamic query (still no idea why you think you need it to be dynamic) that's shown via `dbms_output` manually, just copying and pasting that? Among other things the reformatted code has got a line break in the middle of the first 'lag'; you're missing a closing `)` when you subtract the two sums; and you still aren't using `bull collect`. And you need to call as `GET_DATA('SELECT EmpID FROM CLIENT','''02.12.2022''')` - but still, SQL injection, dynamic, etc...

Comment: Corrected the code added bulk collect still i am getting the invalid operation error